# ngOptions - filter is not working when track by is used in expression

Tags: angularjs

Please see this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/U2oDUPl8w7lSlY8MkVLb?p=preview

Why filter is not working with ng-options having track by in expression and working when using select as?

```
<span> state selector : </span>
<select ng-model="filter.stateID" 
      ng-options="item.stateID as item.state for item in st_option"></select>
<br>
<span>county selector: select as</span>
<select  
      ng-model="filter.countyID" 
      ng-options="item.countyID as item.county for item in co_option | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID }">
</select>
<br>
<span>county selector: track by</span>
<select  
      ng-model="filter.countyID2" 
      ng-options="item.county for item in co_option track by item.countyID | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID }">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ng-options="item.county for item in co_option track by item.countyID | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID }">
```

to

```
ng-options="item.county for item in co_option | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID } track by item.countyID">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
<span>county selector: track by</span>
  <select ng-model="filter.countyID2" 
          ng-options="item.county for item in co_option | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID } track by item.countyID">
  </select>
```